# Get Dictionary Object from Linq context.ExecuteQuery using dynamic query

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, linq-to-sql

I have a query like this

```
string sql = " Select Id, CateId  From StateCategories ";
```

I have several queries selecting two-to-N columns, which I can not decide before because my query builds at run-time.

I want to get (for above query) it's result into a dictionary object without using any model object. Like (what I attempted)

```
var alertCount = context.ExecuteQuery<Dictionary<int, int>>(sql).FirstOrDefault();
```

from the above query, I want `Id` as key and `CateId` as value of dictionary.

Note that in query, there are two columns, which are integer ( at least I assure) .
But it is failed ( and was likely to be )

> Cannot assign value to member 'Comparer'. It does not define a setter.

What can be the better way to do this?

Comment: Instead of saying "What If?" why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: "what if I use Tuple instead of dictionary" - well have you tried that?

Comment: My question if for all `Dictionary`, `Tuple` and I tried selecting multiple columns. If you skip these `what ifs` my question is still hungry for answer. :)

Comment: @JonSkeet, Sir! what I tried is in above question, i.e Dictionary<int, int>. I modified the question

Comment: @MarkC. the example you linked, I already checked. Here you must have `SomeType` first. But I don't want to use any model

Comment: Okay, so you tried one thing - but you thought of some others. Did you try those before asking? If so, what happened? You shouldn't just remove the ideas you had from your question - you should try them, and include that information in the question.

Comment: @Lali, `But I don't want to use any model` then the answer is that you cannot do what you asking if you don't have a model

Comment: If you can loop through the result of the query then I guess you would `.Select(o => new {...});` that out. That is, using anonymous objects.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I tried and the result is in question above. If I select single column (in query), then it returns primitive type (works successfully).

Comment: @Lali, what you want is to have a `Dictionary<int,int>` where the key is the `Id` and the value the `CateId`?

Comment: @Lali just for clarity, what type is `context`?

Comment: @Nkosi System.Data.Linq.DataContext

Comment: @Lali check this article http://www.itdevspace.com/2012/06/datacontext-executequery-extension.html

Comment: People love to down-vote if they don't have reasonable answer. My question is to get anonymous result into dictionary and that is the problem every developer faces.

Comment: No, the result of trying a tuple is *not* in the question above. And please don't assume that downvotes are due to not having an answer - that's just *assuming* that this is a good question, which IMO it's not.

Comment: I didn't tried `Tuple` and I removed it from question, because that was not my core problem and it was emphasized more than the actual problem. So I removed it.

Comment: @Lali did you check the article I linked to. you can use that to ultimately get to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

After some research online and finding the idea from this article from 2012

[DataContext ExecuteQuery extension method returning dynamic objects](http://www.itdevspace.com/2012/06/datacontext-executequery-extension.html)

The following extension method and supporting class can be used to achieve what you are after.

```
public static class DataContextExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> ExecuteQuery(this DataContext ctx, string query, DbParameter[] parameters = null) {
        using (var cmd = ctx.Connection.CreateCommand()) {
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            if (parameters != null) cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            ctx.Connection.Open();
            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)) {
                while (rdr.Read()) {
                    dynamic row = new DynamicRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++) {
                        row[rdr.GetName(i)] = rdr[i];
                    }
                    yield return row;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// DynamicRow class is similiar to ExpandoObject but with addition of indexer
    /// </summary>
    public class DynamicRow : DynamicObject {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _data = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        public object this[string propertyName] {
            get {
                object result = null;
                TryGetMember(propertyName, out result);
                return result;
            }
            set { TrySetMember(propertyName, value); }
        }

        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result) {
            return TryGetMember(binder.Name, out result);
        }

        private bool TryGetMember(string propertyName, out object result) {
            return _data.TryGetValue(propertyName.ToLower(), out result);
        }

        public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value) {
            return TrySetMember(binder.Name, value);
        }

        private bool TrySetMember(string propertyName, object value) {
            _data[propertyName.ToLower()] = value;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Seeing as you are unwilling to use a strongly typed model to get the items out of the context then another option is to use dynamic object. This bring along its own risks as types and properties wont be known till run time.

Using the above code the following will extract the data from the query and you can then use linq `ToDictionary` to convert the records to the desired type.

```
var sql = " Select Id, CateId  From StateCategories ";
var dictionary = context.ExecuteQuery(sql).ToDictionary(_ => (int)_.Id, _ => (int)_.CateId);
```

This should get you started and from there you should be able extract what you need.